# Why is our Gmail add-on listing making browsers run out of memory?

Tags: memory-leaks, gmail-addons

It seems like there is a memory leak in [our add-in listing page](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/priority_matrix_for_gmail/340828899668) because whenever I open that link, my browsers starts running out of memory, eventually bringing the system down to a crawl. Is there any specific element in the app configuration that might be triggering this problem? If I open other add-on listings, there's no such a problem. I tried different browsers on both macOS and Windows, with the same result.

Comment: Well, for the period of time that my devtools work, the page appears to load YouTube 1000's of times.

Comment: Thanks @vcsjones, that's the key. Talking to dev support about this, but removing the app's Youtube video reference solves the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the Youtube link for the app, because once I removed it, the listing started loading automatically.